# Modify a workflow after it has been associated with a library

Tags: 2010, workflow

I need to make some changes to what actions a workflow takes. Currently, the workflow is associated with "My Library", and is manually started and assigned when a document is added to a library.

Currently, it does very little besides notify participants of the start of the workflow and assign them tasks.

What I want to do is edit this workflow so that when it is completed, it modifies a column of the document it is associated with to record the date of completion.

However, the workflow is not listed under the "Workflows" tab of SharePoint Designer for the website (or any other site in the entire site collection) - it is only visible from `Lists and Libraries >> My Library` under "Workflows" ('A list of workflows associated with this list').

I am unable to edit the workflow in any way that I want to from this view, as clicking the workflow just opens up the Internet browser to allow my to change workflow settings, and there are no right-click options from this view.

Is it possible to do what I want, and edit the workflow to do more than it currently does, or do I need to recreate it from scratch with the additional functionality I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it seem that the attached workflow is OOB workflow which comes with SharePoint. [Here is more information on that](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/About-the-workflows-included-with-SharePoint-d9c46b8a-9835-4076-b5d3-6412ce4ca0dc).

And that's the reason you are not able to see the workflow in SharePoint designer.

If you think that default OOB workflows are not fulfilling your requirement, you can create your own workflows using designer.

Reference to create designer workflow: [Introduction to designing and customizing workflows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-32c9c0bf-5e20-4f74-8b9c-d3ea79f2962b)

Comment: You're right, that was it -- I just didn't realize it because of the way the workflow was named. Thank you for those helpful links!